# CORS and address not available issues

Tags: javascript, cors

My team took over a project that doesn't have any documentation and contact with a previous developer. In package.json file I see a script

```
 "start": "http-server -a 192.168.1.200 -p 8080 -c-1 ./app/"
```

but when I run it it throws an error:

> Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 192.168.1.200:8080
>
> ```
> at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1263:19)
> at listenInCluster (net.js:1328:12)
> at doListen (net.js:1461:7)
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
> at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
> at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
> at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
> ```
>
> Emitted 'error' event at:
>       at emitErrorNT (net.js:1307:8)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
>       [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
>       at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)

I tried to add `192.168.1.200 myrealpage.com` to my `/etc/hosts` file but still no luck.

If I start my project on 127.0.0.1 host then app has CORS issues

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.myrealpage.com/api/player/settings' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How can I start the app so it won't have `address not available 192.168.1.200:8080` and CORS issues?

After [this comment from Sar Putnik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60534536/cors-and-address-not-available-issues#comment107092706_60534536) I understood that that `192.168.1.200` is the IP of a previous developer but it is still the mystery for me how did he deal with CORS issues.

Comment: I don't have any experience with node.js or the problem you're facing, but have you tried using a port other than 8080?

Comment: hi! yes, I've just tried `8000` and `3000` but no luck. the same error

Comment: the 192.168.1.200 is your IP / inet?

Comment: no, it was in package.json

Comment: Ok, maybe try using the I don't know what it's called exactly the your IP that that the router assigns. If your on Mac maybe try command ifcongif under en0: use the value at inet. It should have a format like 192.168.X.XXX. Try using this value

Comment: ah, thank you very much. `192.168.1.200` is the port of a previous developer. But now I am confused how did he deal with CORS issues.

Comment: You could just omit specifying the IP, it will default to yours. However, specify the port with `-p 80` (the default being `8080`). If your hosts are setup correctly, you can access it using `www.myrealpage.com`. However, this won't solve the CORS issue if the requests are using HTTPS. Setting up HTTPS locally is a whole other question... Also, make sure that the previous IP was indeed the developer's one. You could break production if that's actually the IP used in the production server/container

Comment: Try using `0.0.0.0` if you want it LAN-accessible.

Answer (score 1):

The IP address in the `package.json` is probably the previous developer's machine IP, the `EADDRNOTAVAIL` clearly show that this IP address is not assigned to your machine on any network interface. Use an IP that your machine owns, either local or not, or don't specify an IP at all.

About CORS, this is a common problem when using a frontend and a backend on two different ports. Depending on which technology you use for your frontend, you can use a proxy that redirects requests on the frontend or on the backend based on a URL pattern (e.g: requests starting with /api are redirected to the backend, the rest is redirected to the frontend). If you can't (or don't want to) do that, you can disable CORS policy by using [Express CORS middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) in order to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.
Note that this is not a good practice in a production environment because that makes you vulnerable to cross site scripting attacks.